# How to install keycloak adapter using maven dependency:copy goal

Tags: maven, adapter, tomcat8, keycloak

The keycloak installation guide says onc has to install the tomcat8-adaptor distribution and one can do this over maven.

The maven coordinates are

```
<dependency>
    <!-- Keycloak Tomcat8 adapter -->
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-tomcat8-adapter-dist</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

The maven repository for this also contains artifacts in the format zip and tar.gz. However when trying to download the artifact I get an error

```
        Unable to find artifact.: Failure to find org.keycloak:keycloak-tomcat8-adapter-dist:jar:3.4.3.Final
```

My maven configuration looks like this.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>

    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-keycloak</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
                        <artifactId>keycloak-tomcat8-adapter-dist</artifactId>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

What is the problem with it?

Answer (score 1):

I had to add a type element, specifying the type of the artifact.

```
<artifactItem>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-tomcat8-adapter-dist</artifactId>
    <type>tar.gz</type>
 </artifactItem>
```